# Can I use snowflake to block downloading data from the client?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

1. End users access snowflake using Tableau, workbench, and cli.
2. The end user looked up the data.
3. The end user wants to save the data retrieved on his computer.

Can snowflake prevent end users from saving locally?

Answer (score 1):

In general, RBAC is the way to limit who sees what data they are supposed to.

To answer your question, as far as downloading the results in products like Tableau, Snowflake doesn't control the behavior of client products when it comes to how the data can be shared.

For downloading results from Snowflake, such as the Snowflake Web UI, there is no way to disable this. If the user can see it and has access to it, they can download it.

Feel free to upvote the idea called "Worksheet: Option to enable/disable ability to download data (csv/clipboard) by user" on this page: 
https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas